# Export Differential All Revisions

Tags: php, excel, phabricator, maniphest

I recently downloaded `Phabricator` to use as my repository management tool. After creating tasks, I can see them on the `Maniphest All Tasks` list with the option of `Export to Excel` as shown below.

[image]

1. How do I integrate the same `Export to Excel` feature for
   `Differential All Revisions` ?
2. Is there any configurable option available to export `Revisions` ?

Being a newbie to `Phabricator`, I am unaware of the coding structure and flow to develop export functionality for revisions.

Comment: @ChadLittle, how can we customize it ?

Comment: It's open source, so you can fork and add whatever features you like. Beyond that it's hard for me to answer the question without knowing why you'd even want such a feature.

Comment: @ChadLittle just like we export tasks, we need this feature to export All Revisions in Differential and send an excel based report on who did what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export to Excel will (eventually) be available in more applications. See https://secure.phabricator.com/T5954